# Can i do ACK/NACK and use prefetch count using STOMP when subscribing to a fixed websocket endpoint which is @SubscribeMapping

Tags: stomp, spring-amqp, spring-websocket

I have a client which subscribes to destination /user/queue/fixed using STOMP subscribe :-

```
destination : /user/queue/fixed
id : 123
ack : client-individual
receipt  : 123456
```

Controller is :-

```
@SubscribeMapping ( "/user/queue/fixed" )
    public void handle( Principal principal ) {
        System.out.println( "principal.getName();" + principal.getName() );
        String queueName = HCCHelper.getClientToQueueMap().get( principal.getName() );
        System.out.println( "queue to subscribe**" + queueName );
        // looping for just testing
        while(true){
            System.out.println("checking for messages....");
            Object o = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert(queueName);
            if(o!=null){
                System.out.println( "Returning mesg**" + o.toString() );
                simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser( principal.getName(), "/queue/fixed", o.toString() );
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            }
       }
```

Can I do ACK/NACK and use prefetch count feature of STOMP when subscribing to such endpoint and expect it to behave same way as how STOMP subscribe to a specific queue works ?
I am getting messages from queue using receiveAndConvert(queueName).
Basically I want the message to remain in the queue if no ACK/NACK is sent or if NACK is sent from the client.
How can I achieve it ?